# Is there a way for me to convert O'reilly to O'Reilly?

Tags: c#, uppercase

I would like to display names in title case and also convert the hyphenated names — such as O'Reilly — properly.

Right now, when I use the `ToUpperCase` function, I get "O'reilly", and that is not what I want.

Here's the function I am using:

```
@functions
{
    public static class TextConvert
    {
        public static string ToTitleCase(string s)
        {
            s = s.ToLower();
            return Regex.Replace(s, @"(^\w)|(\s\w)",b => b.Value.ToUpper());
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do that, accounting for cases like O'Reilly?

Comment: ... and there will be MacDuff and McGregor and ...

Comment: TitleCase it first: `var titlecase = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(s.ToLowerInvariant());` then regex it `return Regex.Replace(titlecase, "['-](?:.)", m => m.Value.ToUpperInvariant());` For ` or - doesnt cover what Filburt mention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with technical tools alone. There are African names that do not start with a capital letter at all. As you can see in this utility (http://www.johncardinal.com/tmgutil/capitalizenames.htm), the easiest way out is to actually maintain a list of exceptions and match your name against it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try It.

```
var titlecase = PrintName("o'riley");
```

Call this function

```
Public static string PrintName(string StrValue)//pass here - o'riley
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(StrValue))
            {
                return Regex.Replace(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(StrValue.ToLower()),
                 "['-](?:.)", m => m.Value.ToUpperInvariant());
            }
            else
            {
                return "Something meaningful message";
            }
        }
```